# how to take a list comprehension's return and use it further in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a function "borrowed", which has to return true if it finds the entered book title in a database of borrowers-to-books. If such book is not found in the database, then that means that the book has never been borrowed, hence the function must return false. So far I have tried a thousand different ways to do this and I am always just a step short of achieving it. Here is my code: I am not sure how to take the list (empty or single string) and use it to compare it against bookTitle and return true if they're the same or false otherwise.

```
type Person = String
type Book = String
type Database = [(Person, Book)]

database::Database
database = [
    ("1", "Haskell"),
    ("2", "Prolog"),
    ("2", "O/S Principles")]

borrowed::Database->Book->Bool
borrowed db bookTitle =
    [loanedBook | (person, loanedBook)<-db, bookTitle == loanedBook]
    --I want to write something like:
    --if above comprehension comes up with a string for loanedBook, then True else False


main = do
print(borrowed database "Haskell")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. Your list comprehension *will be empty* if no books match. Well, you can test that manually:

```
borrowed db bookTitle
   = case [loanedBook | (person, loanedBook)<-db, bookTitle == loanedBook]
       of [] -> False -- Comprehension is empty
          _  -> True  -- Anything but an empty list means, there was a match!
```

Just as well you can use the `null` function for that check.

However, it's not really necessary to construct this comprehension: basically, all you want to do is, check a *predicate* (namely, "second tuple element equal to `bookTitle`") for all elements of a list, and report whether it's true for *any* of the elements. Surprise: there's a standard Haskell function which does exactly that, called `any`.

```
borrowed db bookTitle = any (\(_, loanedBook) -> loanedBook == bookTitle) db
```

Alternatively, you could have first reduced the list to the `loanedBook` titles alone, and then used the even simpler `elem` function:

```
borrowed db bookTitle = bookTitle `elem` map snd db
```

Comment: Thanks very much. "any" worked just perfect. I am still trying to figure out how to use that comprehension as an argument to the "case" statement you mentioned. Thanks again.

Comment: @RumenHristov: In Haskell a list comprehension is just an expression whose value is a list.  Seen from the "outside," it's no different than expressions like `[1, 2, 3]`, `[1..3]`, or `map (+1) `[0..2]`. There are no special rules about where a list comprehension may appear, as long as the expression and the context in which it appears have compatible types it is correct.